# Importing RxJs in small Javascript project

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm trying to import RxJs in a small javascript project using "import" in my script file but I keep on getting the following error:

`Subscriber.js:10 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'rxjs')`

[image]

This is what my html file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
    <title>Load RxJs using import</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Importing RxJs Lib</h1>
    <div>
      <h1 id="info">'loading ...'</h1>
    </div>
    
    <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@7.5.7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.js"></script> -->
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The script file looks like this:

```
// const updateUI = text => document.querySelectorAll('#info')[0].innerText = "finished";

const loadRxJsLib = async () => {
  await import('https://unpkg.com/rxjs@7.5.7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.js');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  loadRxJsLib();
});

document.addEventListener('readystatechange', (event) => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    const { range } = rxjs;
    const { filter, map } = rxjs.operators;

    range(1, 200)
      .pipe(
        filter((x) => x % 2 === 1),
        map((x) => x + x)
      )
      .subscribe((x) => console.log(x))
  }
});
```

Any idea why it's not working? any comment will be highly appreciated

Comment: If you look at the docs it seems you want to import it via script tag like the script tag you've commented, have you followed [this](https://rxjs.dev/guide/importing#cdn) ?

Comment: Yes, I had a look at the guide.My approach is to import from the CDN using "import" in my script file rather than with "<script src=...>" in the index.html. I was expecting this to work and then finally get a reference in window.rxjs... maybe I'm missed something

Comment: To use rxjs with a dynamic import, you'd have to use the return value of the `import()` function. But it would be helpful to also see where you're using rxjs to say for sure.

Comment: @MrCodingB. I have updated the script file in the question according to my test (FYI: I'm just playing around with RxJs in a minimalistic javascript project). I've also recognized that in the end, with dynamic import, I'm getting the reference window.rxjs and my code works, but I still don't get why I am still getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a little bit more, I found out that it might be related to the CDN. I have tried the skypack CDN with the following URL

```
https://cdn.skypack.dev/pin/rxjs@v7.5.7-j3yWv9lQY9gNeD9CyX5Y/mode=imports/optimized/rxjs.js
```

...and I did not get the error anymore